# Accounts tab missing from user page on meta.*.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, beta-phase

I noticed that my [user page](http://meta.gadgets.stackexchange.com/users/87/niall-c) on the [meta site](http://meta.gadgets.stackexchange.com/) for the [gadgets SE](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/) doesn't have an accounts tab, but the [equivalent](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/users/87) page on the main site does.  I found the same on Web Apps and for other users on both sites.

Why would the meta site and the main site be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, see the meta /faq for why this would be.

(hint: there is no reputation on the per-site child meta sites.)